# Custom image and switch not showing in collection view controller at right place

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My requirement is, I need to populate 10 cell's in collection view controller and I need to display in 6Th cell battery status and in 7th need to switch. The remaining cell is not required to show the battery status and switch. I am adding these two (battery status & switch) through programmatically.

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if indexPath.row == 6 {
            let percentage: CGFloat = 0.4

            let imageview:UIImageView=UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 30, height: 18))
            let img : UIImage = UIImage(named:"batteryIcon")!
            imageview.image = img

            let batteryView  = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 30, height: 18))
            cell.addSubview(batteryView)
            let colorRect = CGRect(x: batteryView.bounds.origin.x, y: batteryView.bounds.origin.y, width: batteryView.bounds.width * percentage, height: batteryView.bounds.height)
            let coloredView = UIView(frame: colorRect)
            coloredView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            batteryView.addSubview(coloredView)
            cell.contentView.addSubview(imageview)
        } else if indexPath.row == 7 {
            let switchDemo = UISwitch(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 40, width: 37, height: 18))
            switchDemo.isOn = true
            switchDemo.setOn(true, animated: false)
            switchDemo.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.70, y: 0.70)
            switchDemo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
            cell.contentView.addSubview(switchDemo)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Here it is Working fine. But the problem is when I call "collectionView.reloadData()" Instead of showing battery status and switch 6Th and 7Th cells, Those two appearing in other cells also.

I am not getting, What mistake I am done.
For a better understanding of my requirement, I am sharing an image.
[image]

Comment: Because your cells are reusable you will need to handle removing the items you add to them on reuse (aka your reload). It would be best to create subclassed cells with the content you want and then use those cells at the index's you specify. That way you have your cells that don't have these custom components and you have your cells that have the custom components. You can then handle the reuse properly in the custom cell class.

Comment: `UICollectionViewCell` (same for `UITableViewCell`) are reused. That's the concept you are missing. Because they are reused and you do `addSubview()` on them, that's causing your issue.

Comment: FYI - if you find yourself calling `addSubview` in `cellForItemAt` then you are doing things incorrectly. Use different custom cell classes that contain the appropriate views. Then in `cellForItemAt` you should dequeue the proper cell type based on the index path.